# Why isn't one 'bash' command working at startup

Tags: bash, lubuntu, startup, upstart, bashrc

I am working on a VM with Lubuntu 14.04,

I have created a script a.sh,

```
#!bin/bash
echo "aaaa" >> a.txt
```

And my /etc/rc.local file is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

bash /home/sentinel/a.sh
echo "hey" >> /home/sentinel/b.txt
exit 0
```

On rebooting my machine, I can see b.txt built with content as `hey` but a.txt is not being built. Can somebody please help me here?

Comment: No, b.txt doesn't exist. By built I mean created. That means second last line of the rc.local is executed, but 3rd last isn't. @JacobVlijm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mention complete path  where a.txt should create.

Your script should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "aaaa" >> /home/sentinel/a.txt
```

I have tried this my self before posting here .

added line `rc.local` as

```
./home/sentinel/a.sh
```

save it and restart your PC.

Comment: Did you mean `. /home/sentinel/a.sh` instead of `./home/sentinel/a.sh`? The first is doing `source` using an absolute path, the second executes the script by a relative path.

Comment: Do you even bash, bro?

Comment: I just tried this on my computer, and it doesn't seem to work. I copied everything as mentioned here, still didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: How you are trying ?

Comment: @Daniel , I am trying to help with what i know and here i am , where you are then...i too have a pc and i can type anything. If possible encourage,guide,help else shut your mouth and hands. Thanks for stopping by.

Answer (score 3):

Missing leading / char.

```
#!bin/bash
```

should be

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: Sharp! however, since he is calling the script with `bash /home/sentinel/a.sh` it works anyway... So he escaped luckily.